# How to configure timestamp in Weblogic 12c Diagnostic log file name

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I'm working on Weblogic 12.2.1 Version.

I have to save my weblogic domain diagnostic log file names in the following format: "***myserver_diagnostic-yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm.log***".
If date is "*4th July 2018, 02:56PM*" then the file should be as: "***myserver_diagnostic-2018-07-04T14:56.log***".

Current configuration in the Weblogic Enterprise Manager is:
***${domain.home}/servers/${weblogic.Name}/logs/${weblogic.Name}-diagnostic.log*** 
Which resulting the file name as: ***myserver-diagnostic.log***

How to provide timestamp in the above configuration?

Comment: Try something like :  ${weblogic.Name}_diagnostic-%yyyy%-%MM%-%dd%T%hh%:%mm%.log

Comment: @AndreGelinas This pattern is not working from EM. It works only for the logs which are able to configure from Weblogic Administration Console.

Answer (score 0):

For WLS Diagnostic log files, unfortunately, you don't have the option to add timestamp as part of the filename. Diagnostic log files are handled by Oracle Diagnostic Logging (ODL) and this uses numbers when rotating files. ODL does allow rotating on time-based conditions, but the filename will always use a number, no matter what type of condition you select. For more details, see section "Configuring Log File Rotation":
https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/12.2.1.3/asadm/managing-log-files-and-diagnostic-data.html#GUID-391C6ADF-1D5D-46B4-A7F6-C9CF855F8AF6

---

Now, if you wanted to add the timestamp to WLS log files (not the diagnostic log files, but the main WLS log files), here is an excerpt from the documentation explaining how WLS can use timestamp to name the log files, when log file rotation is enabled:

> If you enter the following value in the File Name field:
> myserver_%yyyy%*%MM%*%dd%*%hh%*%mm%.log, the server's log file will be
> named myserver_yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm.log.
>
> When the server instance rotates the log file, the rotated file name
> contains the date stamp. For example, if the server instance rotates
> its local log file on 4 March, 2005 at 10:15 AM, the log file that
> contains the old log messages will be named
> myserver_2005_03_04_10_15.lognnnnn. (The current, in-use server log
> file retains the name myserver_yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm.log.)

Here you can find details on how to set the log filename from WLS console (for version 14.1.1.0):
https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/standalone/weblogic-server/14.1.1.0/wlach/taskhelp/logging/RotateLogFiles.html

And here is the same documentation page, but for version 12.2.1.3:
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wls/WLACH/taskhelp/logging/RotateLogFiles.html